# error chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a select box that when clicked on it (and run jQuery code in js file) get in console chrome (Ctrl+J) this alert, i don't know what is this error?(i have chrome 16.0.912.63)

How do I solve this?

> GET
>   http://d3lvr7yuk4uaui.cloudfront.net/items/dom/20111209/l/localhost.js
>   403 (Forbidden)
>
> chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:11
>
> --------------- mouse down -----------------------------
>
> chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:42empty -
>   parent element isnt as source
>
> chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:63send
>   request: 
>   2chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:18
>
> --------------- mouse up -----------------------------
>
> chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:11
>
> --------------- mouse down -----------------------------
>
> chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:63send
>   request: THE PORT
>   chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:18
>
> --------------- mouse up -----------------------------
>
> chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:11
>
> --------------- mouse down -----------------------------
>
> chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:42empty -
>   parent element isnt as source
>   chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:63send
>   request: 
>   2chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:18
>
> --------------- mouse up -----------------------------
>
> chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:11
>
> --------------- mouse down -----------------------------
>
> chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:42empty -
>   parent element isnt as source
>   chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:63send
>   request:  chrome-extension://dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb/cs.js:18
>
> --------------- mouse up -----------------------------

**Update:**

This is my js code:

```
$('select[name="stayn"]').live('change', function(){
    var insert = $(this).closest('.column');
    var input_val = $(this).closest('.column').prev('.column').find('input').val();
    var this_val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'get_price',
        data: {relation: input_val, staynight: this_val},
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data ,function(idx, val){
                insert.after('<input name="child"  id="'+val.child.replace(',', '')+'"');
            })
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you post that code ?

Comment: I updated it, Please see again

Comment: In here is my full html: http://pastebin.com/uZRGxkfp, but this problem there is in all html page in my folder and get this error by chrome.

Comment: The pastebin mentioned above is removed, btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to disable the "Babylon-Pro" Chrome extension (extension id dhkplhfnhceodhffomolpfigojocbpcb). It's what's throwing most of these errors.